# IP Adress Spofing via ncat,nc etc

Tags: ip-spoofing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Netcat IP Spoofing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14046/netcat-ip-spoofing)

I want to ask one question to you.

My friend and i playing game together.He is using below command this computer.

```
ncat -u -c /bin/bash --allow 1.1.1.1 -l 443
```

And i must connect my friend computer.But i must my ip spoof(1.1.1.1)

I am doing

```
ncat 192.168.71.1 443 -s 1.1.1.1
```

or

```
ncat 192.168.71.1 443 -g 1.1.1.1
```

nothing.

How to connect my friend's computer command prompt?